# How do I create a partition in order to dual boot Win7?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I just got a new laptop from a friend and I'm decent with computers, however, I am a HUGE noob when it comes to Linux OS (besides backtrack (; ). I downloaded `gparted`, but there is no way that I am able to create a partition as they are all mounted and in use. Will I need to back up everything on this HDD and then wipe it in order to make a partition to dual boot Windows? I'd rather not go through all that trouble. I have a valid copy of Win7 Ultimate and I'd really like to have a nice laptop with a couple of decent OSes on it. Please help!!

Comment: You need to run GParted from a LiveCD, so that the OS isn't mounting it's own partitions.

Comment: it was better to have a Gparted screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click on a partition with GParted, and select `Unmount`. From there, you should be able to shrink your partition. You probably won't need to make any backups, although backing up is still a good idea, especially when editing partitions (just in case something goes wrong).

Or, you can shrink the Windows partition from within Windows, by right-clicking on My Computer, select `Storage` from the pane on the right, and click `Disk Management`. Right-click the partition you want to shrink, and select `Shrink Volume`. From there, you can specify how many MB's you want to remove from the total size.

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick response! the only problem is, when i select "unmount" it gives me this error: "The partition could not be unmounted from the following mount points:

/

Most likely other partitions are also mounted on these mount points. You are advised to unmount them manually."

Comment: also, when i boot up my win7 disk in order to install it, it says that the partition is not big enough ):

Answer (score 0):

You can't unmount an in-use partition. It's sometimes possible to unmount a partition after you stop using it -- for instance, if you log out of a regular user account and log in as `root`, you can unmount `/home`. (Ubuntu doesn't give `root` a password by default, though, so doing this would require deviating from the accepted Ubuntu practice.) Most Ubuntu users also create a simple setup with just one or two Ubuntu filesystem partitions. This can make it difficult or impossible to resize partitions while the Ubuntu installation is in use.

As a practical matter, therefore, resizing Ubuntu partitions often requires booting an emergency disc/live CD. Your Ubuntu installer should do fine -- just select the option to "try before installing" (if I recall the phrasing correctly).

Comment: Yeah I felt loke a big fool when it hit me tjat gpart was a BOOTABLE exe so I'm making a decently sized partition.  I want to thank everyone for all the great help and quick responses! I think I found my community :)